# How to use multiple css contents in a same class

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

One content (`:after` for box and `:before` for arrow) property for `data-tooltip` and I want another content property for the field icon using custom icon fonts like fontello or fontawesome. How can I achieve this.??

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether it's possible for an element to have more than one `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element at a time, that's not possible in CSS2.1. The reason is twofold:

- Any element can only have exactly one `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element at a time due to cascading rules. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111751/what-happens-if-multiple-classes-define-a-before-pseudo-element/14111903#14111903) for details.
- Even if an element could have more than one of each kind of pseudo-element, the browser wouldn't know how exactly it should lay all of them out in the formatting structure. This can be worked around by having CSS offer a way to [specify multiple pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465817/multiple-pseudo-elements) or [nest pseudo-elements within other pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007546/adding-pseudo-elements-after-pseudo-elements/9007628#9007628), but neither of these ideas have been implemented.

If you need a complex structure that cannot be achieved with a single element with one `:before` and one `:after` pseudo-element, you will need to modify your HTML to accommodate this structure.